# sql query to insert multiple records

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a table "user" and another table "test"

My test table contains some of the userids. I want to check and insert into table "test" all those userids which are not there.

can you please help me with SQL query ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Step 1 - select the records you want.  Step 2 - look at the test table to verify they are not there.  Step 3 - write an insert query based on Step 1.

Comment: If userid is a UNIQUE/PRIMARY KEY, just INSERT IGNORE all the userids. The IGNORE keyword will IGNORE any duplicates. If userid is not a UNIQUE/PRIMARY KEY, make it one.

Answer (score 2):

You may looking for this

```
INSERT INTO Test(Col1,col2..)  
SELECT Col1,col2.. FROM UserTable WHERE UserTable.UserID NOT IN (SELECT UserID FROM Test)
```

Comment: thanks. I want to add them into table test :-)

Comment: Thanks. But I still don't see any updates in my table. 
nothing is inserted

Comment: it says! 
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: You need to specify columns which are need to insert in test table

Comment: OK.
In test table there are two columns, 1-testId, 2-UserId
I am free to add any testId,
your support is appreciable

Comment: These are very basic questions, if you are set testId as identity column i.e auto increment then you just need to insert UserID column values

Comment: Why down vote ?care to comment out

Comment: I didn't. 
I gave you +ve